# Airport Express as a wifi access point connected by Ethernet cable to a modem?

Tags: airport

Will an Apple Airport Express be able to do what I need?

I work on a laptop running Win7Pro, and my internet feed comes to a Netgear DM111P cabled modem, which I connect to the laptop using an ethernet cable. The modem sits in my office at home, and I'm fine with this set-up when I'm working in that room. But I want to be able to connect wirelessly to the internet sometimes from other rooms in the house (max distance say 10 metres through 2 doors), using a wifi access point device (WAPD) that I leave in the office. So the idea is that I leave one end of the ethernet cable plugged into the modem, and I move the other end between the laptop (when I'm in the office) and the WAPD (when I want to use internet elsewhere). The procedure needs to be quick and simple. I don't want to have to configure software all the time. I just want to be able (when leaving the office) to power up the WAPD, take the ethernet cable out of the laptop and plug it into the WAPD, then leave the room with the laptop; and (when coming back into the office) turn the WAPD off, take the ethernet cable out of the WAPD and plug it back into the laptop. Also I want to turn the modem off when I'm not on the internet.

Is the Airport Express a WAPD of this kind?

Answer (score 1):

The unit should do what you want. No guarantee on the bandwidth as the range increases, but if your Internet connection is less than 30Mbps, and you're only using it for Internet access, then having the wireless component shouldn't slow you down.